# Properties of a function with an increasing nth derivative

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying for an analysis qualifying exam and came across a problem that I think is interesting and haven't been able to crack.

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $n$-times differentiable, and suppose that the $n$-th derivative $f^{(n)}$ is an increasing function. Given that $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$ and that $f(1) = 1$, show that

1. $f^{(n)}(1) \geq n!$
2. $f^{(k)}(1) \geq 0,$ for $1 \leq k \leq n-1$,
3. $f(3) \geq 2^n$.

edit: (this proof is invalid: I assumed $f'$ is increasing, when only the $f^{(n)}$ is given to be increasing.)

For the second claim, we can use the mean value theorem and induction:
$$ \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{1} = 1 = f'(c), 0 < c < 1 $$
and since $f'(x)$ is an increasing function, $f'(1) > f'(c) = 1$. Now assuming that $f^{(n-1)}(1) \geq 1$,  we again apply the mean value theorem:
$$ \frac{f^{(n-1)}(1) - f^{(n-1)}(0)}{1}  = f^{(n-1)}(1) = f^{(n)}(c) \geq 1 $$
for some $c \in (0,1)$. Then because $f^{(n)}$ is an increasing function, 
$$ f^{(n)}(1) > f^{(n)}(c) \geq 1 $$
which proves claim (2).

Any ideas on how to proceed for the other two claims?

Comment: You weren't given that $f'$ is increasing, were you?

Comment: Oh, you're right! Just the $n$th derivative. So that "proof" for the second claim isn't true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f^{(n)}(1)= qn!$ then $0\le f^{(n)}(x)\le qn!$ for $0\le x\le 1$ because it is increasing, hence $0\le f^{(n-1)}(x)\le qn!x$ for $0\le x\le 1$ by integration. Repeat integration (i.e. use induction on $k$) to find $0\le f^{(n-k)}(x)\le qn!\frac1{k!}x^k$ for $0\le x\le 1$ and finally $f(x)\le q$ for $0\le x\le 1$. From $f(1)=1$ we infer $q\ge1$. Also, we have shown $f^{(k)}(1)\ge 0$ on the way.

We have $f^{(n)}(3)\ge n!$ because it is incresing, again.
By integration (using the 2.), $f^{(n-1)}(x)\ge n!(x-1)$ for $x\ge 1$ and by repeating (i.e. again induction on $k$) $f^{(n-k)}(x)\ge n!\frac1{k!}(x-1)^k$ so that finally $f(3)\ge 2^n$.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about working backwards through integration like that.